# Issue customizing Devise controller :require_no_authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've generated additional devise controllers and I want to modify the Registrations controller to only allow `super_users` to access the new, create, and delete option on that controller. I've implemented a method `super_user?` which returns a boolean depending on the users super_user state.

```
def super_user?
   if user_signed_in? 
       current_user.super_user == true ? true : false
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

Then in the controller I redirect and render a flash message if the `super_user` method returns false. When no user is signed in or a signed_in user without super_user abilities tries to access the sign_up page they are redirected as planned.

```
def new
    if super_user?
      super
    else
      redirect_to root_url
      flash[:warning]= "Only Administrators can add accounts"
    end
  end
```

However when a user with super_user abilities is logged in they are redirected to the homepage and this message is logged to the console:

`Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected`

From my understanding while researching this topic, this method is part of Devise and is created to redirect users that are already logged in from sign_up and sign_in pages since they are in fact already users. However in my case I want to super_users who are logged in to be able to access the sign_up page to sign_up additional users. Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

So I actually figured out what was going on and I wanted to answer in case anyone else ran into this problem.

if you simply add `skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication` to the RegistrationsController then every thing functions as expected. I found the answer [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2811)